# How to place a dynamic multiline UILabel in tableHeaderView

Tags: swift, uilabel, multiline

[image]I created an xib view linked to a UIView class called InstructionView. That view contains nothing but a UILabel constrained to margin from all sides.

The number of lines of the label is 0 and line break is set to word wrap.

This view is then added to a stackView. And that stackView is then set as the tableView’s tableHeaderView.

```
override func viewsToAddAfterTitle() -> [UIView] {
    var views: [UIView] = []
    if let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(Constants.Nibs.instructionView, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? InstructionView {
        view.fillWithInstruction("A long text that needs more than 1 line")
        views.append(view)
        view.setNeedsLayout()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    return views
}

func addTableHeaderView() {
    if let viewHeader: ViewHeader = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(Constants.Nibs.viewHeader, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? ViewHeader {
        viewHeader.setTitle(titleText: headerTitle())
        var arrangedStackSubviews: [UIView] = viewsToAddBeforeTitle()
        arrangedStackSubviews.append(viewHeader)
        arrangedStackSubviews.append(contentsOf: viewsToAddAfterTitle())
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: arrangedStackSubviews)
        stack.distribution = .fill
        stack.axis = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.vertical
        stack.alignment = .fill
        stack.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        tableView.tableHeaderView = stack
    }
}
```

fillWithInstruction function is called when I load the nib. I call it to set the text of the label.

```
func fillWithInstruction(_ instruction: String) {
    instructionLabel.text = instruction
    instructionLabel.sizeToFit()
}
```

I tried calculating the intrinsicContentSize and set constraints on the height of the label based on that. I tried placing the label inside a view and/or a stack.

None of what I tried worked. I want the label to show more than 1 line if that text needs more than 1. But currently it always shows 1 line.

Comment: Maybe try to add  the amount of lines programatically in func viewsToAddAfterTitle()as theLabel.numberOfLines = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here’s the real deal:

Create this extension:

```
extension String {
func heightNeededForLabel(_ label: UILabel) -> CGFloat {
    let width = label.frame.size.width
    guard let font = label.font else {return 0}
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
    return boundingBox.height + 20
}
```

}

The + 20 is just to give it some more space

And call it like this:

```
func fillWithInstruction(_ instruction: String) {
    instructionLabel.text = instruction
    guard let instructionLabel = instructionLabel else {return}
    instructionLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: instructionLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 2, constant: instruction.heightNeededForLabel(instructionLabel)))

}
```